# Telegram bot sendMessage parse_mode generates HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

Using the HTTP API of telegram to send message in PHP like the following:

```
$msg = "New Comment is **added** from:\n".$domain;
    file_get_contents('https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN:CODE/sendMessage?chat_id=@MYCHANNEL&text='.$msg.'&parse_mode=markdown');
```

Just adding the last parameter `&parse_mode=markdown` causes 400 bad request. Removing it, everything works fine.

However, removing `\n` from the `$msg` string makes it works fine.

Now, I don't know why the new line `\n` leads to 400 bad request. Also, I don't know how to add new line to the message body!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the msg;

```
$msg = urlencode("New Comment is **added** from:\n" . "mydomain");
```

[image]

The url is ended after the newline was found, therefore PHP cant send the request, resulting in a 400.